# Python - Dealing with Unicode Decode Error 'utf8'

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

Since I was unable to find a one stop answer to the problem, I am posting my solution after learning from different threads:

I am importing data using `pandas` as follows

```
import pandas as pd
data=read_csv(".../file.csv",encoding='utf8')
```

This resulted in the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 352: invalid start type
```

To counter this when I changed the encoding to Latin-1

```
data=read_csv(".../file.csv",encoding='Latin-1')
```

This resulted in the error when trying to apply `vectorizer.fit_transform()`

```
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @aryamccarthy the error was creeping up because of encoding issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the data using 'Latin-1' encoding:

```
data=read_csv(".../file.csv",encoding='Latin-1')
```

Next when executing the `vectorizer.fit_transform()` using the following:

```
vectorizer.fit_transform(train['desc'].values.astype('U')) #This example is for a specific dictionary type which I had named train with desc as an key
```

This should resolve the issue